# Visual Studio Language Service - Add Additional File Extension at Runtime

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I am working on a custom LanguageService extension package for Visual Studio 2013. I have successfully registered a file extension using the ProvideLanguageExtensionAttribute with my package.

```
[ProvideLanguageExtension(typeof(MyLanguageService), ".myext")]
```

I would like to allow users to configure which file extensions can use my language service. Is it possible to register additional file extensions at runtime to my LanguageService?

Note: I am mostly interested on whether or not there is any mechanism for registering the file extension via code at runtime (such as a service). The details about how to surface this to the user through the UI is a separate concern and not really what I am asking about at this time.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm trying to do the same thing but haven't been able to find any information about assign file extensions to a language service dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code you use the `ProvideLanguageExtensionAttribute` to link a certain file extension with your language service. The `ProvideLanguageExtensionAttribute` class inherits the `RegistrationAttribute` class, which can be used to register package information during installation (works for Visual Studio 2010 and any newer version). I guess, Visual Studio is not going to reflect that attribute any time the language service extension gets loaded, instead it reads information from the registry...

Another good example for a usage of the `RegistrationAttribute` is the [ProvideFileFilterAttribute](http://pytools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Python/Product/PythonTools/ProvideFileFilterAttribute.cs) which can be found in the *Python Tools for Visual Studio* project published on codeplex. It is used to extend the list of file filters of Visual Studio´s open file dialog and it could give you an idea how an implementation of a registration attribute could look like... and I would say that you could easily come up with a service which can add or remove file extensions which will be obtained by the IDE on next start...

I am also working on a custom language service extension which registers both file extensions and -filters; so I just examined the registry to find the information I provided via attributes; and these are my findings...

File extensions which appear in the open file dialog´s filter list are stored under the following key...

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
    {version}_Config\Languages\File Extensions\{extension}
```

Whereby the key´s default value contains the `GUID` of the language service...

```
Default => {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

In addition, there´s another key, but I am not sure if values are obtained from attributes...

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
    {version}_Config\Diff\SupportedContentTypes
```

File extension which are associated with a project factory and an editor extension are stored under the following key...

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
    {version}_Config\Projects\{project-factory}\FileExtensions\{extension}
```

Whereby the key contains the `GUID` of the project factory. The key contains a single value pointing to the editor factory...

```
EditorFactoryNotify => {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

In my language service I have also overridden the `GetFileExtensions`- and `GetFormatFilterList` methods of my `LanguageService` implementation...

Comment: I have yet to see `GetFileExtensions` get called. Do you know when it is called? I'm trying to allow users to dynamically assign file extensions to my own language service as well, like the OP, but it's proving very difficult!